# Restore course backup via terminal for moodle (solved)

Tags: moodle

I need to restore about 70 course backups to a course area (id 20) in moodle. Is this possible via a terminal (ubuntu) via loop? THX

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a category? You can restore to a category via the command line

```
php admin/cli/restore_backup.php --file=/backupfolder/backupfile.mbz --categoryid=20
```

And just for reference, backup via command line

```
php admin/cli/backup.php --courseid=99
```

Or

```
php admin/cli/backup.php --courseshortname=mycourse
```

Restore via command line

Answer (score 0):

We have create a bash-script for more backups

> read -p "Path to backup: " -r DIRECTORY
> read -p "Category-ID:" -r CATEGORYID
>
> BACKUPS=$(ls $DIRECTORY)
> array=( $BACKUPS  ) for i in "${array[@]}" do
> cd httpdocs/
> echo ""
> echo ""
> echo "restored $i"
> echo ""
> sudo -u www-data php admin/cli/restore_backup.php --file=$DIRECTORY${i} --categoryid=$CATEGORYID   done

View the moodle documentation here

> https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Course_backup